# 22.04 is suggested on Ubuntu's website but not in the repository

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c # It SHOULD work as 22.04 is released now
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d # This is the only solution now which is abnormal
Checking for a new Ubuntu release

= Welcome to the Ubuntu 'Jammy Jellyfish' development release =

''This release is still in development.''
............
```

The current mirror is `archive.ubuntu.com`. The current OS is `21.10`.

Comment: The ISO has been released for **new installs**, upgrades from 21.10 are not yet opened up which is normal. The earliest they'll open up is next week just like every thing cycle.

Comment: See the [22.04 Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668): "Upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10: Upgrades to 22.04 LTS are currently not enabled (due a bug with snapd and update-notifier) but will be in the next couple of days."

Comment: The bug has been solved and the package with the fix can already be installed
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1969162 so should be fine to upgrade now

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The ISO has been released for **new installs**, upgrades from 21.10 are not yet opened up which is normal. The earliest they'll open up is next week just like every prior cycle.

For users of 20.04 LTS, the *release-upgrade* will **not** be seen until after the release of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS as per documentation and prior cycles; ie. about a further three months wait - as it's assumed LTS users prize *stability*.

If you look at the file https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release you'll see why you're getting the behavior you're experiencing; as Ubuntu Release Team make that change (*allowing upgrades*) when they deem it *fit* and ready for existing users.

At this moment in time, as stated, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is deemed *fit* for **new** installs.

If you don't want to wait; you can use the `-d` option which will cause the following file to be used instead https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development thus the path will be seen.

Those files will be changed when the *Ubuntu Release Team* deem the systems ready for users, the aim of which is to ensure *stability* for existing users.

Comment: If you're the fearless sort (or a healthy dose of foolhardiness will do just as well) then you can try this from a terminal - https://gist.github.com/avranju/4bd6ba153d5e9c6ca9c288eae6a6ad79 (GitHub gist because this site doesn't format code properly in comments).

This will start the upgrade process. Again, only attempt this if you don't particularly care if at the end you have to repave the whole system. I was on 20.04.1 and being foolhardy, I tried it and it worked. Caveats: [1] it’s not an unattended process and [2] if everything freezes, be patient and wait.

Answer (score 13):

Generally the `do-release-upgrade` option will not show `.0` releases. When the first point-release, Ubuntu 22.04.1, is made available later this year, people will be able to upgrade their installations via the `do-release-upgrade` option.

In the meantime, you can use `-d` to install the current stable release (despite the `-d` meaning "development release").

Comment: Thank you! I will manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` now.

Comment: The upgrade option for 21.10 should show up in a few weeks if there are no major issues. On the other hand, 20.04 won't see it till August when 22.04.1 is released.

Comment: Is it safe to upgrade with option `-d`? Just it be sure that it will not pull some bleeding edge packages which would destabilize the system.

Comment: @SudhirSinghKhanger you can answer your question if you try out.

Comment: I do a clonezilla backup of the OS partition before doing ANY upgrades. then I can take chances.