# How do I upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 now? Are most guides simply wrong?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

There are many guides e.g.
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish or https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version/ that suggest the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 is possible now. They rely on `sudo do-release-upgrade -c/-d`.

However, at the moment (22nd Apr), I get

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '21.10' available.
```

and

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

I have read that for the normal upgrade path, one would go from 20.04.04 to 22.04.01 (say in August). However, the claim is that `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` would work now (as it's effectively a dev upgrade path. However... see above.

So my question is: **Are many of the guides (that claim upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 is possible now) wrong? Or is there something wrong with my system / have I misunderstood something? If so, what?**

(For clarity: I'm on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` but my software management is now set to update to every minor version. There are other answered question on askubuntu, but they do seem to have asked before the release on 21st. Apologies if this is a duplicate!)

Comment: Release upgrades for LTS releases are not pushed until the first point release. 22.04.1 isn't expected until August 2022.  Also, release upgrades are not typically available immediately after a new release. The ISOs for new installations are available and you can certainly (re)install 22.04 if you must have it this very moment.

Comment: I'd check you have applied all upgrades for your existing system.  If it was me I'd `sudo apt update` & read the output looking for anything missing, anything that could corrupt your system & prevent upgrade (esp. 3rd party sources), then `sudo apt full-upgrade` ,,, reboot if needed, then try again.  I know the `-d` option works as we use it in QA (*Quality Assurance*) and it worked, thus I'd check your base system & ensure you don't have issues there (maybe check mirror from the `sudo apt update` detail I mentioned earlier etc)

Comment: Many of the guides "out there" do indeed suggest using `-d` to skip the wait until the first point release. My opinion is that those guides are suggesting rather reckless action -- the delay until the first point release is done for good, sensible reasons to lower risks of LTS users. If you're in a hurry to upgrade, maybe you shouldn't be using an LTS. Folks who want newer software should be on the Standard 6-month release track anyway.

Comment: I have the same problem as of 23/Apr/22. I'm in the UK, maybe they are doing a slow roll out.

Comment: I've also seen this comment: See the 22.04 Release Notes: "Upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10: Upgrades to 22.04 LTS are currently not enabled (due a bug with snapd and update-notifier) but will be in the next couple of days." - see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403610/22-04-is-suggested-on-ubuntus-website-but-not-in-the-repository

Comment: I would say (and this is regardless of the OS flavor you are using): never upgrade your OS. It is just too complicated process to be fully tested by developers to be guaranteed to work in all possible scenarios. Use your current OS as long as possible, then backup all your config and data, reinstall the new system and restore config and data. Several manual adjustments of the configuration may be needed. You should expect that. That's the only really safe way to "upgrade".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer to: "Or is there something wrong with my system / have I misunderstood something?"  Yes.

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d` works just fine on 4/22/22 on my 20.04 system:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,261 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,262 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

Reading cache
```

..and then it goes on from there

I cannot answer the first part about "many of the guides" because I will not take the time to look at them

However, as far as the part about what specifically is wrong with your system, I believe that it is your setting in Software & Updates.  Make it look like this:

[image]

When I set this to "For any new version" I got the same error you did.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - however, I do have the notify set to 'for any new version'. I tried ` sudo do-release-upgrade -d` again, but still get that the message above.

Comment: @bjohas you are getting the error **because you have it set to "any new version"**. You need to change it as shown in the answer. That is specifically what I said in the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, that works, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a possible interpretation of the situation.

- The 21.10->22.04 will only be available a week after the initial iso release. Therefore, 21.10->22.04 and presumablyt 20.04->22.04 with 'notify me' set to `any version`, a standard upgrade isn't available just yet (`-c`).
- However, the for 21.10->22.04 dev path (`-cd`) is available.
- The 20.04->22.04 (non-dev) will only be available in September. Therefore, with 'notify me' set to `LTS`, will only be available in September.
- However 20.04->22.04 is available as a dev path. Therefore, with 'notify me' set to `LTS` works now (`-cd`).