# Why can't I upgrade from Xubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS via the GUI?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, xubuntu, 22.04

[image]

As you can see, I am on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS and have all of my settings as [this guide](https://docs.xubuntu.org/latest/user/C/migrating-upgrading.html#upgrading) says they should be. Despite this, I see no option to upgrade to 22.04 LTS. What have I missed? I'm sure that it's been released.

Comment: Updates to existing LTS installs aren't pushed until the first point release (ie 22.04.01) comes out. You will have to wait until August for that.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403870/how-do-i-upgrade-from-20-04-to-22-04-now-are-most-guides-simply-wrong

Comment: If *also* you read release notes; you'd have read details like "*Users of Ubuntu 21.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 22.04. Users of 20.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 22.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 4th of August.*"    https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/   We're not after 4-August-2022 yet and upgrades from the prior LTS-cycle aren't open yet.   The Xubuntu *docs* tells you how to upgrade when *Ubuntu Release Team* open the upgrade path (Upgrades are the same for main Ubuntu & all *flavors*)