# ubuntu 20.04 user , when they will get 22.04 update

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, updates, update-manager

can anyone tell me why I am not getting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS update? I am new to Linux and read somewhere fresh boot is better than updating the old Ubuntu.
thanks in advance

Comment: If you’re running 20.04, then you will start to see notifications to upgrade when the `.1` release is made available. [This answer explains in more detail](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403615/1222991) 

Comment: It's been released for new installs, but is not deemed ready for any *release-upgrades* as per documentation which states it'll open **after** release.  The Ubuntu Release team will discuss opening it for existing Ubuntu 21.10 users on Monday as per every prior cycle; but they don't discuss it for existing 20.04 users until **after** the release of Ubuntu 22.04.1 as per all prior cycles (*21.10 was the last release in this full development cycle; Ubuntu 22.04 was the last LTS from the last full development cycle so it has a much larger jump & it's assumed LTS users prize *stability*)

Comment: Don't be so eager to upgrade, upgrade (even if well tested by the developers) usually means problems.
Use the current OS as long as possible, then do a fresh install of a new version and migrate your settings and data.