# New OS release not found - unable to upgrade

Tags: do-release-upgrade, 22.04

I have attempted to upgrade to 22.04 LTS using the update manager, but also from the commandline using `sudo do-release-upgrade` but nothing happens in either case. My system is set to look for 'any version' (not just LTS) and to check daily.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Thank you! OK. Will wait another week for the upgrade to become available.

Comment: It may become available in a few days... some *fixes* are currently in -proposed for *jammy*, when those have *dropped* (ie. moved to -updates or -security) the *Ubuntu Release* team will re-evaluate opening the upgrade for current 21.10 users..   I'd suggest waiting until it's offered if you can; as there are always reason for why the *Ubuntu Release* team do what they do.

Answer (score -1):

I am supposing you are in ubuntu 20.04.

1. Goto Software and Updates. Click on Updates tab and Click on notify me a new ubuntu version and select For any new version.
2. Upgrade to 21.04
3. Open terminal

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: These are the exact steps I have followed. I repeated the whole sequence now and nothing happens before the last command (do-release-upgrade) but the release I am presented with is a development release of jammy-jellyfish. I have not set my system to look for development releases.

Comment: And he is also not on LTS only, so he is probably using 21.10 now

Comment: You can't upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 - it's EOL & [Ubuntu upgrade tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) will **not** let you upgrade to an EOL erlease.   https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/

Comment: I am currently on 21.10. I have switched the update setting back and forth between any release and lts. Now, at least, I am offered the possibility to upgrade, but why does it present me with a 'development release' of 22.04? Is this actually the official release, but just an error in the message I get, or is it in fact what it says it is?

Comment: Please see the answer I wrote in my suggested duplicate link; what you describe is what **should happen** for the reason I tried to describe in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403610/22-04-is-suggested-on-ubuntus-website-but-not-in-the-repository/1403615#1403615  @AriBördeKröyer

Comment: I upgrade yesterday from 20.04 to 21.04 to 22.04