# Ubuntu 22.04 Multiple Issues

Tags: unity, mysql

Have done six installations on different hardware.  Installing from two different iso images downloaded from the Ubuntu.com download page and using both dvd and flash drive installation media produces similar results.

1. Installation process is extremely slow regardless of hardware or installation media and often errors out requiring a reboot.
2. Clicking on application icons in the left menu bar either works only once or not at all.
3. Installing applications from the snap store produces errors and / or inconsistencies in application performance / operation.  I have particularly noticed this with MySQL-workbench and Firefox.
4. No immediate upgrade path is immediately available from earlier LTS versions though this may turn out to be a mixed blessing considering the above issues.

Comment: First, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question and answer site and we require that you don't ask multiple unrelated questions together. You can ask more than one question if necessary.  We also ask that you please search/research before asking. This prevents duplicate questions and wasted time and effort. Searching ahead of time will also make it easier for you to write a good question with sufficient details to understand the problem. FYI, the upgrade path from one LTS to the next is not offered or recommended until the first point release. This won't be until August.

Comment: There is a remarkable dearth of actionable information here. Could you [edit] your question to: (1) define "extremely slow" (2) share the specific error messages you are seeing (3) check the contents of the log files in `/var/log` to see if there are hardware-related issues (4) upgrade from ... where? 22.04 is the most recent release.

Comment: I suggest that you please close this question since it is too broad. You can ask another question for each of your other issues. To improve your chances of getting an answer, add details! Instead of telling us you are getting errors, you should copy/paste the whole error as well as the steps needed to reproduce the error. Also share the research you found before asking. What did you find and why didn't it work for you?

Comment: 4. [Duplicate] See http://askubuntu.com/questions/1403610. The upgrade path from earlier LTS releases is scheduled to open in early August 2022.